# Intuitive explanation of law of large numbers

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables, law-of-large-numbers

If $Y_n=\frac{X_1+X_2+...X_n}{n}$ and $X_i's$ are i.i.d and $E(X_i)=0$, when we want to show that $Y_n$ converges to zero almost surely we need to prove that

$$\mathbb{P}\{w:Y_n(w)\rightarrow0\}=1.$$

Here we choose a $w$ for all $Y_n's$ and hence one $w$ for all $X_i$'s. However, in real world we expect that if we realize every random variable $X_i$ independently then the sum would converge to zero. In other words, in realization of random variables we do not choose same $w$ for all $X_i$. $X_1$ can choose $w_1$ and $X_2$ can choose $w_2$ and so on. But $Y_n$ would converge to zero.

I am a little bit confused with the definition of almost surely convergence that why we choose same $w$ for all random variables while this is not the case when we want ,for example, to verify the law of large numbers using simulations.

Comment: $w$ is an outcome of the underlying random experiment, but what exactly is that random experiment? I think the answer to that will clarify the issue. The random experiment is not flipping a coin once (for example), it is flipping the coin countably many times. When you perform this experiment, you will almost surely observe that the sequence of numbers $\{Y_n\}$ approaches $\mu = E(X_i)$.

Comment: But in flipping coins, when you flip a coin it means that you choose $w_1$ for the $X_1$. Then you flip the coin again and you may choose $w_2$ which is different from $w_1$. But when you want to prove the almost sure convergence, you choose same $w$ for all $X_i$'s. These two scenarios are totally different.

Comment: When you flip the coin countably many times, the result is $w$. For example, one possible value of $w$ is $(H, T, T, H, T, H, H, …)$. This infinite sequence is one single outcome of your experiment.

Comment: Based on your example and based on the intuition it totally makes sense. However, in most of textbooks they have the following example: Suppose that $U$ is a uniform random variable between $[0,1]$. Then $X(w)=w^n$ where $w$ come form $U$. Then we can conclude that $X_n\rightarrow 0$ a.s. Because for almost every $w$, $w^n$ is converging to zero. But in this example, we chose same $w$ for all the $X_n$'s. In your example, you chose $w_1=$Head for the $X_1$ and $w_2=$Tail for $X_2$,... and you said all this experiment is just one trial. Can you see my point?

Answer (score 0):

To me, the "almost surely convergence" simply means something will happen with a probability, and this probability is 1. 
The "almost surely convergence " is different than something will surely happen, it is a slightly weaker certainty.

Every possibility we have Sample Space, Borel set, and Probability space. w represents outcomes, which are from the sample space. 
So, for almost all outcomes(w) from Sample space, we have the probability equals to 1. 
For the same outcome w, if its associated Y_n converges to its associated X, then  Y_n converges almost surely to x.

Comment: I know that almost surely is different from surely. It means that the measure of $\{w\}$ which has the above property is one. My question is different from your answer. I restate it again. In the proof of almost surely, we choose same $w$ for all $X_i$'s. But consider flipping a coin. First you choose a $w_1$ for $X_1$ by flipping a coin. Then you flip the coin again and then you may choose $w_2$ for $X_2$ which may be different from $w_1$.

Comment: I will update my answer.

Comment: Actually I found the answer of question. I was thinking that when we toss a coin infinitely many times, the sample space is ${H,T}$. But every $w$ is an infinite dimensional vector like $(H,T,H,H,T,...)$. Moreover, we need to use the Kolmogorov's extension theorem to state that there exists such a probability space for infinitely many random variables.